# get value of an element inside an associative array from a table

Tags: php, mysql

```
$arr = ['b1' => 'banners/5B5C4965B9A50.jpg', 'vid' => 'vid.mp4', 'linked' => 'linkedabc'];
```

I inserted the above array into a table (using `json_encode`) so the content of the filed named `map` is:

```
{"b1":"banners/5B5C4965B9A50.jpg","vid":"vid.mp4","linked":"linkedabc"}
```

Now I want to get and loop this array:

```
$sql = "select map from params where what = 'artb'";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$arrx = $st->fetch();
//$arrx = json_decode($arrx); - also tried here

foreach($arrx as $key => $el){
    if($key == 'b1') {getb1($el);}
}

function getb1($el){
    echo $el;
}
```

Result:

`{"b1":"banners/5B5C4965B9A50.jpg","vid":"vid.mp4","linked":"linkedabc"}`

I'm expecting `banners/5B5C4965B9A50.jpg`.

What's wrong?

Comment: use `echo $e1->b1`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, tried and result is - `Notice: Trying to get property 'b1' of non-object `

Comment: json_decode to be used with second parameter set to true

Comment: But wait you try to decode an array, not a json here. Your question states that $arrx is a json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `json_decode` first and then access the key directly.

```
$arrx = json_decode($arrx['map']);
```

To access `b1`,

```
echo $arrx->b1;
```

Your updated code snippet will look like this,

```
$sql = "select map from params where what = 'artb'";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$arrx = $st->fetch();

foreach($arrx as $key => $el){
    $elMap = json_decode($el['map']);
    echo $elMap->b1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $arrx = json_decode($arrx,true);
foreach($arrx as $key => $el){
        if($key == 'b1') {getb1($el);}
    }
```

You need an array before you loop it. You try to access a json object the way you access array which is not possible.

Your code will work perfect after that.

```
    $data = '{"b1":"banners/5B5C4965B9A50.jpg","vid":"vid.mp4","linked":"linkedabc"}';

    $arrx = json_decode($data,true);


    foreach($arrx as $key => $el){
        if($key == 'b1') {getb1($el);}
    }

function getb1($el){
    echo $el;
}
```

And the output is `banners/5B5C4965B9A50.jpg` as expected

Comment: tried and the result is - `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: Based on your question $arrx is a json object. Check my updated solution i provided a code walkthough.